# exporting from powershell to txt file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to set up a scope on dhcp via powershell and export info to txt file. My code does what it needs to do, but when i export to txtfile with | out file it only exports the reserved ip not the ip-range and exclude-range what do i need to change

```
#scherm leegmaken
Clear-Host

#import module dhcp server
Import-Module DHCPServer 

#DHCP service oppstarten
Set-service dhcpserver –startuptype automatic 
Start-service dhcpserver
#Een scope aanmaken
netsh dhcp server 192.168.126.140 add scope  192.168.126.0 255.255.255.0 "Scope1"
#de iprange van de scope meegeven
netsh dhcp server 192.168.126.140 scope 192.168.126.0 add iprange 192.168.126.160 192.168.126.199
#de excluderange meegeven
netsh dhcp server 192.168.126.140 scope 192.168.126.0 add excluderange 192.168.126.180 192.168.126.189
#Een ip reserveren
netsh dhcp server 192.168.126.140 scope 192.168.126.0 add reservedip 192.168.126.182 f8db7f4fa490 "reservationEx1"



#de iprange, ecluderange en het gereserveerde ip weerrgeven en wegschrijven naar txt file
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show iprange +

netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show excluderange +

netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show reservedip | Out-File "C:\TEMP\Ballali.DHCPConfigInfo.11792.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I already found the solution.
I need to use the parrameter -Append to not overwrite the txt file.
and put the out-file cmd instead of +

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of operations.
Your code:

```
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show iprange +
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show excluderange +
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show reservedip | Out-File "C:\TEMP\Ballali.DHCPConfigInfo.11792.txt"
```

It is equivalent to this!

```
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show iprange +
netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show excluderange +
(netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show reservedip | Out-File "C:\TEMP\Ballali.DHCPConfigInfo.11792.txt")
```

What you are doing is

1. Writing the **reserved ip address** list to the specified file.
2. Putting **1st, 2nd ip range list** and result returned by Out-File together.

Because I prefer to **declare explicitely**, I would do like following

```
$iprange = netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show iprange
$exclude_range = netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show excluderange
$reserved_range = netsh DHCP server \\W2K12PWSHLL01 scope '192.168.126.0' show reservedip
($iprange + $exclude_range + $reserved_range) | Out-File "C:\TEMP\Ballali.DHCPConfigInfo.11792.txt")
```